# Bootstrap football team dynamic layout

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a layout to display a fantasy league team, originally I had it with player names in a table view but I want to change that to a graphical representation that looks a bit like a team line up.

Although I can get it similar to what I want I'm not very experienced in writing css, the site is written in PHP so I'm thinking that I will have to have a few styles based on how many players are in a position and then use php to swap these dynamically, unless there is a better way.

My question is how do I go about getting the positions central like I have done with the goal keeper position and get them inline, I am using `float: left` to get the positions inline but cant get them central with that.

```css
.section-heading{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
.section-heading-text{
    text-align: center;
}

.section-content{
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#009b29+0,009b29+20,61bf7a+20,61bf7a+40,009b29+40,009b29+60,61bf7a+60,61bf7a+80,009b29+80 */
    background: #009b29; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #009b29 0%, #009b29 20%, #61bf7a 20%, #61bf7a 40%, #009b29 40%, #009b29 60%, #61bf7a 60%, #61bf7a 80%, #009b29 80%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #009b29 0%,#009b29 20%,#61bf7a 20%,#61bf7a 40%,#009b29 40%,#009b29 60%,#61bf7a 60%,#61bf7a 80%,#009b29 80%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #009b29 0%,#009b29 20%,#61bf7a 20%,#61bf7a 40%,#009b29 40%,#009b29 60%,#61bf7a 60%,#61bf7a 80%,#009b29 80%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#009b29', endColorstr='#009b29',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    height: 300px;
}
.gk{
    text-align: center;
}
.kit-image{
    height: 40px;
    width: 35px;
}
.defender{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-box">
  <div class="section-heading">
    <h2 class="section-heading-text">Team Name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="gk">
          <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/keeperKit.png" class="kit-image">
          <div>
            Goal keeper
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="defender">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution proposal, that provides the creation of *col-centered* and *row-centered* css classes, and apply them as follows:

css:

```
.row-centered {
   text-align:center;
}


.col-centered {
   display:inline-block;
   float:none;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="section-box">
  <div class="section-heading">
    <h2 class="section-heading-text">Team Name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="gk">
          <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/keeperKit.png" class="kit-image">
          <div>
            Goal keeper
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div class="defender col-centered">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender col-centered">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender col-centered">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="defender col-centered">
        <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
        <div>
          Defender
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just by using bootstrap columns and adding offset to the first one, and then adding to all columns text-align: center attribute.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="gk">
      <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/keeperKit.png" class="kit-image">
      <div>
        Goal keeper
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="defender col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">
    <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
    <div>
      Defender
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="defender col-sm-1">
    <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
    <div>
      Defender
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="defender col-sm-1">
    <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
    <div>
      Defender
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="defender col-sm-1">
    <img src="www.gamingcentury.com/img/outKit.png" class="kit-image">
    <div>
      Defender
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in css:

```
.defender{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's worked quite well